# GPT accidentaly overwrote by MBR in non-native USB SATA dock

Tags: gpt, mbr

Sorry if I miss some solution, but I can't find issue like my one, especially looking into gpart status in answers.

What I have got:

1. Seagate 4000GB 3,5" drive ST4000DM000
2. Probably shipped as
   mounted in USB 3.0 SATA dock, Seagate (unknown model, the case is
   incomplete and USB port is damaged)
3. Trekstor USB 2.0 SATA dock
   DSMMU-S-SU-a
4. Unitek USB 2.0 SATA dock Y-1031

1-3 is my friend's stuff, 4th is mine.

Well. What probably happened. My friend bought 4TB HDD in USB dock case, it can be used even under Windows XP as he says. The case is broken now and I can't confirm that yet.

When he broke the socket, he simply pulled the disk from the native case and put that in Trekstor case. And probably Trekstor controller wrote an MBR to the disk somehow.

When I try to run HDD with my Unitek dock, it shows in gnome-disks as 4 TB drive. When I try my friend's Trekstor case it shows only 2 TB storage device!

So I assumpt my Unitek dock is compatible with GPT and I want to use it for recovery.

Now, what I can see on the disk (plugged via Unitek).

On Linux, there is classic MBR, 500 GB unknown partition and 3,5 TB free space.

On Windows 7, MBR, 500 unknown GB partition AND TWO unpartitioned spaces (WTF?).

And what is most important, on Linux gpart can't see even broken GPT file, only MBR:

```
# gdisk 
GPT fdisk (gdisk) version 0.8.10

Type device filename, or press <Enter> to exit: /dev/sdb
Partition table scan:
  MBR: MBR only
  BSD: not present
  APM: not present
  GPT: not present
```

Probably the disk was shipped formatted as one 4 TB big NTFS partition, under GPT partition table.

Maybe I can copy GPT table (the disk beginning and the copy at disk ending) from someone that has identical drive, using dd command? If not, how to fix it, and how to see is there a copy od GPT at disk ending? Can i back up the GPT table over that MBR, taking data from disk ending?

Comment: Some, but not all, USB enclosures and adapters convert blocks of eight 512-byte sectors into single 4096-byte sectors. This conversion wreaks havoc with any pre-existing partitioning data, if you move a disk to or from such an enclosure. If you try to write to such a disk on the "wrong" adapter, your data goes bye-bye. It's not 100% clear to me what disks have been moved from one enclosure to another, but it sounds like you've been juggling them a lot, which will produce all manner of problems.

Comment: Well, for now - gparted didn't find any partition, but I maybe can try now testdisk… Huh.

Comment: Yup – testdisk has found valid NTFS and also listed directories structure! Maybe I'll recover all the data, now I got to do chkdsk from Windows, that I can do on Monday, 'cause I'm now on TeamView. I'll set the flag [solved] when I make myself sure the partition is truly recovered.

Comment: Once you recover data, **DO NOT** move the disk to another enclosure.

Comment: Well, Rod, I moved disk to another enclosure, but checked that both acts the same.
I used testdisk and now I got weird situation.
Two USB cases, on both: any Linux see valid GPT with valid NTFS on it, and I can read and write files. On any Windows 7 or 10, there's a valid GPT with unknown RAW partition on it, that Windows want to format (so cannot do chkdsk or so). What can be wrong yet?

Comment: The algorithms used to detect whether a disk is GPT or MBR vary from one OS to another. This is why [hybrid MBRs](http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/hybrid.html) are useful (although dangerous). Chances are something similar is happening to you -- you've got a hybrid MBR or something that accidentally has a similar effect. The solution is likely to be to regenerate the protective MBR on the disk. You can do that with `gdisk`: Launch `gdisk` on the disk, type `x` to enter the experts' menu, type `n` to produce a new protective MBR, and type `w` to save the changes.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is solved.

Well, fixing the broken USB socket in the original Seagate USB case did the trick.

But when I put the disk into the case, I again saw nothing in disk managers – just empty, unpartitioned disk. Searching for partitions again in testdisk worked once more. The GPT partition table has been found again and saved. The difference is, whole partition could be now seen then under any OS – Linux and Windows XP, 7, 10.

Conclusion: probably the Seagate case has some internal and writable flash/EPROM memory to save its own GPT (it's one kilobyte if I understood that well), and it treats it as HDD sectors, pushing real HDD sectors after own memory.

The data was not touched when I swapped disk because the partition was preceded and followed by two 8-megabyte unpartitioned spaces, so there was much place to wrote GPTs or any other trash.

That's the only explantation I can imagine for now. Still the puzzle is, why the disk can be seen under Windows XP, but it's not a problem.

Thanks for all the help.